# Data Structure for Transaction Queue

Tags: .net, algorithm, data-structures, transactions, queue

Is there a more appropriate/efficient data structure for a transaction queue than using a `List`. I've tried using `Queue`s and `Stack`s, but neither fits the bill correctly.

I've outlined my problem in detail below with examples showing why I've ended up with a `List` for the time being. Any suggestions of alternative data structures (preferably, but not limited to, those with an implementation in the .Net BCL) are appreciated.

#### Problem

Maintain a transaction queue of `Insert()`/`Delete()` operations that will be later persisted to arbitrary backing storage when the user calls a `Commit()` method or discarded when they call the `Rollback()` method.

Operations must be enacted on the in-memory state of the object affected since subsequent operations may rely on the state of the object created by previous operations.

#### Example 1

I have an object `obj` that starts as an empty collection. The user inserts an item `i` and then deletes it.

They then call `Rollback()`. Given the following data structures for the queue, the following happens in the rollback:

- Queue - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → incorrect, since `obj` should remain empty after rollback.
- Stack - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → correct, since `obj` remains empty.
- List (Reverse Traversal) - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → correct, since `obj` remains empty.

If they call `Commit()` instead, the following happens:

- Queue - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → correct, since `obj` remains empty.
- Stack - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → incorrect, since `obj` is not empty.
- List (Forward Traversal) - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → correct, since `obj` remains empty.

So, for this example, Queue works for `Commit()`, but not `Rollback()` and a `Stack` shows the inverse behaviour, **but** both are incorrect. The only `List` shows correct behaviour, though note that for the commit, we traverse the list in a forward direction while for a rollback, we traverse the list in a reverse direction.

#### Example 2

Now, consider having again an object `obj` that this time starts with the single item `i` contained in itself.

This time, the sequence of operations is a Delete of `i` followed by an Insert of `i`.

If they call `Rollback()`, the following happens:

- Queue - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → incorrect, since `obj` ends up as empty.
- Stack - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → correct, since `obj` contains the single item `i` still.
- List (Reverse Traversal) - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → correct, since `obj` contains the single item `i` still.

If they instead called `Commit()`, the following happens:

- Queue - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → correct, since `obj` contains the single item `i` still.
- Stack - `obj.Insert(i)`, `obj.Delete(i)` → incorrect, since `obj` ends up as empty.
- List (Forward Traversal) - `obj.Delete(i)`, `obj.Insert(i)` → correct, since `obj` contains the single item `i` still.

As with the previous example only using `List` is correct in both cases, but we have to traverse it in different directions depending on whether we are committing or rolling back.

### Bottom Line

While using a `List` is not inefficient in itself, I just wondered whether there was a more appropriate data structure that is a better fit for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you could use a `LinkedList<T>`. It's like a `Queue` + `Stack`: you can add and remove from head and from tail, and in both cases it's `O(1)` (but it's normally slower than a `List`, for reasons connected to memory locality and the need to allocate memory for each adding of an element).

(Please, don't kill me because I said a `LinkedList<T>` is like `Queue` + `Stack`… I know the difference… I meant only that it can be used in both ways at the same time.)

I'll add that, if you consider `Rollback` an "exception" (something rare), then you can use a `Queue` and, when you have a `Rollback`, `Reverse` the output of the `Queue` using LINQ. Being an "exception", it can be slower (and you don't even need LINQ… You can do a `ToArray()` and traverse the array in reverse order).